# What happens if I have 2 branches (1 is an updated version of the second one) and a change occurs in the initial branch?

Tags: git, azure-devops

So we recently started using branches (we use Azure DevOps), and this one issue has been making us confused as to how to use our branches.

If I have a branch where I am currently working on a new feature in (say branch 1.1), but an issues occurred in a previous branch (say branch 1.0) that has been published and we need to fix it and republish it (1.0) without publishing the new branch (1.1). Should I implement the change on both the old (1.0) and new branches (1.1) or is there a way to integrate that change into both branches (1.0 & 1.1) without doing the work twice?

Comment: Cherry-pick or merge. There are reasons to use either one; see [Raymond Chen's series on this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325).

Answer (score 1):

Better Solution here is cherry-pick. Sometimes you need a commit from another branch and you don't want to merge them.
for picking the commit you can use `git cherry-pick <hash_id>`

here is the documentation of git about cherry-pick: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

or if you want to pick changes to a special file you can use :

```
git restore --source= <branch_name> -- <file_name>
```